# Add.Js returns error 400 (Bad Request) Shopify

Tags: python, shopify, cart

I'm having trouble with posting a request to a shopify site. Every time i get a 400 error can someone help ? I have tried it with different varient ids but its still not working.

Upate:
I tested request.session but still no sucess.

If it's helpful here are the docs for the Cart API: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart

```
endpoint = 'https://example.com/add.js'

post1 = requests.post(endpoint,{
    'items':[
        {
        'id':'0123456789',
        "properties": "{}",
        "quantity": "1"
        }
    ]    
}, headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
})
```

Update:

Another Example:

```
endpoint = 'https://example.com/add.js'

post1 = requests.post(endpoint,{
    'items':[
        {
        'id':0123456789,
        "properties": {},
        "quantity": 1
        }
    ]    
}, headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
})
```

I tried it both ways but it's still not workin.

Comment: Do you have a valid customer session?

Comment: And just to confirm, you're using your actual store's address as the endpoint and just using `example.com/add.js` for the sake of this question, correct?
Also, you don't need quotation marks around the `{}` for your `properties`, that part accepts a proper Javascript object of key/value pairs :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by valid customer session but if i tried to add session (with requests.sessions )but it's still not working.

Comment: Yeah i used example.com/add.js only as an example. And thanks i tought i had to put the quotation marks there.

Comment: If somebody could help would be really helpful :)

Comment: Is this endpoint a defined api? Can you link to its documentation or show the actual JS file so we can understand what request body it accepts?

Comment: Thanks for the reply here is the link for the doc: https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the API docs, `id` and `quantity` are numeric (integer) values and `properties` is an object. If you construct your request payload as such it should work.

Guessing from your mention of `requests.post` here, I assume you're coding in python right? If so, this should get you your desired request.

```
endpoint = 'https://example.com/add.js'

post1 = requests.post(endpoint, {
    'items':[
        {
          'id': 123456789,
          'properties': {},
          'quantity': 1
        }
    ]
}, headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
})
```

Comment: Thnks for the reply, its still not workin i tried it both ways but it's still not workin. I don't know why but it makes no difference.